# After review, we still get "sign in with google temporarily disabled for this app"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

We have a mobile app and our users got a

> "sign in with google temporarily disabled for this app"

When they tried to login their YouTube account with iOS (There's no problem with Android devices).

We submitted a verification request long time ago, and we got from YouTube an email (May 26th 2020),(May 26th 2020):

> "Hi Adam,

> Thanks for working with us on the YouTube API Services compliance review. We have completed your review and do not require any further actions from you at this time.

> We may reach out again to re-review your API Client for compliance with YouTube API Services Terms and Policies.
> We appreciate your time working with us on this and please continue to comply with the YouTube API Services Terms and Policies."

Since then, nothing had changed and our app hasn't been verified yet, and our users can't connect with their youtube accounts.

What can we do? We are just waiting and we don't even know how to contact YouTube and ask about our specific case/project.

Thanks you,
Adam.

Answer (score 0):

> sign in with google temporarily disabled for this app

Means that your application has not been verified by google.  You need to go through the verification process.

You can use a project for development without verification. However there are some limitations (more information [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)). Basically, you have now reached the limit of 100 users accessing the application.

If you still havent heard anything from google after they say they have verified your application I think the only thing you can do is to submit it again and double check that you are using a client that was created under the project that you requested verification for there's really nothing else you can do.

Comment: I wish there was a support email address that I can say what is my project number and they will simply check the status. It sounds weird to re-submit it and maybe the process will start from the beginning...